# What is System-on-Module exaclty?

Tags: microcontroller, microprocessors

What is System-on-Module? How is it different from Single Board Computer (SBC)?

Furthermore, its usage is mentioned in prototyping. But I am not sure how it's helpful?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key difference between the two is that a System-On-Module (SOM) usually has to plug into a port on an external host board so that the module can get power and io.  Usually there's a development host board with the SOM that's used initially, but the intent is often to develop a custom host board with the module port on it so that peripherals, io connectors, etc. external to the module are part of what is customized. It also gives some flexibility in future processor upgrades, or even complete processor changes.

If you wanted to modify a Single-Board-Computer (SBC), one would have to respin the entire PCB and assembly tooling to accomplish the same.

Of course the other difference is that the SBC is just that, a single board, while a working SOM system is at least two boards.

Answer (score 0):

A [Computer on Module](https://www.toradex.com/computer-on-modules) (COM) or [System on Module](https://www.toradex.com) (SOM) is a small form-factor computing solution that consists of the application agnostic hardware and software for developing any embedded product. In terms of software, the COM contains the Operating System, Device Drivers and associated BSPs. System developers can focus on the application specific part (Hardware: Display, Interfaces, Peripherals; Software: Application, UI) by using an off-the-shelf COM, and thus accelerate time-to-market without compromising on product development cost & risk.

A COM/SOM is generally built around microprocessors, system-on-chips, or microcontrollers. They integrate additional devices and peripherals which are needed to realize a fully functional computer, which normally includes RAM, non-volatile storage and power supplies.

Answer (score 0):

[System on Module](http://www.inforcecomputing.com/products/system-on-modules) is a complete chip on a single printed circuit board including clock, microprocessor, RAM, flash memory, Ethernet and I/O controllers. It is also called a Computer-on-Module (COM) and, like other single-board computers, does not typically have I/O sockets for direct connection to peripherals. They must be plugged into the main board of another system, which completes the I/O pathways to the outside world.